# What is the biorthogonality condition for a generalized adjoint eigenvalue problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Building off of this post, [What are the relations between eigenvectors of $A$ and its adjoint $A^*$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409108/what-are-the-relations-between-eigenvectors-of-a-and-its-adjoint-a)

**How can I derive the bi-orthogonality condition for a generalized eigenvalue problem?**

Generalized eigenvalue problem:

$Ax = \lambda Bx$

Its adjoint:

$A^H y = \mu B^H y$.

An inner product is: $<a|b> \equiv a^H b$

$A, B$ are complex square matrices. $H$ is the complex conjugate transpose operation.

**My attempt:**

1. The adjoint problem must satisfy: $<y|(A-\lambda B)x>=<(A^H-\lambda^* B^H)y|x>$ which equals zero because $(A-\lambda B)x = 0$
2. Another way to see the adjoint problem is: $<(A^H -\mu B^H)y|x>=<y|(A-\mu^* B) x> = 0$
3. By inspection, we can equate $<(A^H-\lambda^* B^H)y|x>=<(A^H-\mu B^H)y|x>$
4. We can see that $y^H A x$ cancels out from above
5. The remaining term is: $y^H (\mu^* - \lambda) Bx=0$
6. This is equivalent to $<y|(\mu^* -\lambda)Bx>=<(\mu-\lambda^*)y|Bx>$
7. Finally, the bi-orthogonality condition is $(\mu-\lambda^*)y^H Bx = (\mu-\lambda^*)<y|Bx>=0$
8. This demonstrates that if the typical and adjoint eigenproblems are connected by a shared eigenvalue, the eigenvectors are not orthogonal. However, if the eigenvectors are not connected by a shared eigenvalue, then the eigenvectors are orthogonal. This also shows that the typical and adjoint eigenvalues are different by a complex conjugate.